# Particle moving in circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A particle is moving in a circular motion attached to a wire which produces de movement. T is the tension of the wire induced by the particle.

I'm not grasping why isn't the force T equal to -mgcos(a), but instead equal to mg/cos(a) (according to the solution). Shouldn't Newton's Third Law be used here?[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particle is not accelerating in the vertical direction, so there is no net vertical force on the particle, therefore all vertical components of forces must cancel. The forces that have a vertical component are tension and weight. Thus, we have $$T \cos (\alpha) = mg$$ leading to $$T = \frac{mg}{\cos (\alpha)}$$ as claimed.

The forces along the direction that you stated do not cancel because there is a net centripetal acceleration, directed inwards. This adds to the horizontal component and will need to be considered as well.

Comment: I see. I thought the centripetal acceleration was exactly produced by the horizontal component of T (Tx/m) because T is what is inducing the circular motion.

Comment: what is the meaning of the force which is the component eN of the weight? The force which has the value mgcos(a) and what is the acceleration causing it? Wouldn't it be centrugal acceleration?

Comment: @tmvaz: Yes, the centripetal force required for circular motion is provided by the horizontal component of tension, while the weight is balanced by the horizontal component of tension. $mgcos(\alpha)$ is not really useful to us here as there is a net inward acceleration *which has a component* along the tension. Therefore, you cannot say that *T* and $mgcos(\alpha)$ balance each other.

Answer (score 1):

From your figure it looks like you are talking about conical pendulum 
Indeed Newton's law is used since it is not moving in vertical direction force should be balanced so T cos(a) = mg 
In it is moving in horizontal circle so T Sin (a) should provide necessary centripetal acceleration 
And if you want to write the Newton's equation along string length , you can do that do 
Correct equation will be T - mg cos (a) = component of centripetal acceleration * mass

Comment: So the horizontal component of T provides the centripetal acceleration, right? And what is the meaning of the eN component of the weight? I assume it shouldn't be equal to T or else there wouldn't centripetal acceleration. Is it produced by a centrifugal force? Isn't it going to "change the direction" of an apparent weight?